# I have Tornado installed, but i can't run my script. I keep getting 'ImportError: No module named tornado'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I am new here.
I am currently running a virtual environment, however I can't seem to run the script that I am testing.

I have tornado 4.4.2 installed in my virtual environment.

Please refer my snippet code as follwing:

```
from tornado import httpserver, httpclient, ioloop, web, websocket, gen
```

But, I keep getting this error as following:

```
"C:\Users\User\.\main.py"line 7, in <module>
    from tornado import httpserver, httpclient, ioloop, web, websocket, gen
ImportError: No module named tornado"
```

Comment: To ask a potentially very obvious question, are you _running_ the code in your virtual environment?

Comment: Yes I am running the code in my virtual environment